# How to send 200 OK response after receiving post request

Tags: google-apps-script, shopify, webhooks

Trying to reveive a webhook and transforming it into a new row in sheets. To confirm that apps scripts received the webhook I need to send a 200 OK response. So far i fail to send that 200 OK response. I know that due to the fact that the webhook gets sent over and over again and shows up more than once in my sheet.

My code so far:

```
var SHEET_KEY = "abc";
var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";

function doPost(e) {
  handleResponse();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(); // how to send a 200 OK response?
}

function handleResponse() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_KEY);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;

  var row = [];
  row.push(["test"]);
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
}
```

When i make a post request with the app Postman i receive a status 200 OK response.

**Update:**
This way works in Postman & with the webhook:

```
  // send 200 OK status back to confirm receiving webhook
  var response = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput();
  return response;
```

Comment: Try to work with public API's if you haven't done yet. Here is a [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) that can help you do the first steps. `Google Apps Script can interact with APIs from all over the web. This guide shows how to work with different types of APIs in your scripts` and you can refer to this [post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009AtaIAE) for further details about sending 200 response for webhook.